# Update attribute directive value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular js and I have tried few sample code. I am trying something but it is not working. Following sample code will you more detail on this.

**Html Code**

```
<body  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
        <div repeat-hello-world="{{repeat}}">
            <button ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">{{i}}</button>
        </div>
</body>
```

**Angular JS Code**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('repeatHelloWorld', ['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        compile: function(element, attributes) {             
            var hello = function(){                 
                 var nodes = element.children();
                console.log(nodes.length);
                 for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; ++i){                 
                  console.log(i);    
                  angular.element(nodes[i]).attr('data-alert',i);   // This is not working
              }           
            }

            element.ready(function(){
                  hello();  
            });

            var nodes = element.children();
              for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; ++i){
                  console.log(nodes.length);
                  console.log(i);
                  angular.element(nodes[i]).attr('data-alert',i);
              }           
        }
    }
}]);
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives']);

/* Controllers */
function testController($scope) {
    $scope.repeat = 5;
}

myApp.directive("alert", function(){     
    return function(scope, element, attrs){

        attrs.$observe(attrs.alert , function(newValue){
            console.log('newval' + newValue);
        });
        element.bind("click", function(){
            console.log(attrs.alert);           
        });
    };
});
```

You can see one line that "This is not working". When I try to change value data-alert ( This is attribute directive) but it always display 0. I also try to observer change in value but it is not working as well.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U7N9n/2/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: I have added fiddle link and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are relying on adding the alert attributes *after* the ng-repeat has been rendered (meaning after the $digest phase). By then, its too late - you've missed the opportunity to modify the DOM so that they get compiled and linked properly.

The way to fix this is to put your ng-repeat in a parent  element and declaratively add 'alert' attributes:

```
    <div repeat-hello-world="{{repeat}}">
        <span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
        <button data-alert="{{i}}">{{i}}</button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

[Here is a Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xULY/1/)

Comment: Yes you are right for that but what if we have to do update after rendering DOM. This is what I am searching for.